# How to find all HamiltonianPath

Tags: graphs-and-networks

[image]

How to find all HamiltonianPath from 1 to 27? FindHamiltonianPath only show one path.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Typing code (or copying and pasting) is the standard here instead of uploading images (screenshots).

Answer (score 1):

```
g = GridGraph[{3, 9}, VertexLabels -> Automatic];
paths = FindPath[g, 1, 27, {VertexCount[g] - 1}, All];
HighlightGraph[g, PathGraph[#]] & /@ paths
Clear[g, paths]
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: If it answers your question you can accept it by clicking on the left.